# Eclipse to Android Studio, not able to run in simulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Have converted an existing project from Eclipse into Android Studio. All imported fine, but when trying to run it on simulator, get message attached.  This is my first Android project, so still catching up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) library included twice ? If you are using the `compile` line

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:+'
    }
```

remove it from `libs` folder, so the library is not being compiled twice.